# How to configure redmine with https, in linux apache hosting server (i.e just host, bluehost)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, apache, redmine

How to configure redmine with https, in linux apache hosting server (i.e just host, bluehost).

normal http site is working. but it is not working in https. I am getting error like"Page not found".

Comment: Have you bound the ports properly?

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is to configure apache or nginx to redirect http to https

```
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName redmine.example.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/redmine/public

    RewriteEngine on
    ReWriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R,L]

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/redmine_error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/redmine_access.log combined
```

don't forget the VirtualHost directives

you will need to enable ssl on your webserver